# Make network manager control individual devices?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, kde, cinnamon

I recently changed from Cinnamon to KDE Plasma 5 and I feel like I have googled everything I can. On Cinnamon Network Manager allowed me to turn off and on my two wifi adapters separately. Is there anyway to add that functionality with Plasma? There is only one switch that turns off both adapters. I have only been able to get it to show the device names by the networks they found.

[image]